# PHP: Converting utf8 chars from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, html-encode

I have a longtext in my db where i have some special chars like `&Atilde;`

How i can convert it to "`à`"? I've tried using utf8_encode and _decode but it seems not work.
Document charset is utf8, and longtext field too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about encoding but html entities : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.html-entity-decode.php